# hide back button when tab bar controller is added in navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a navigation controller (navC) and I have a view controller (ViewC) which is a view pushed from root controller. I have hidden back button for ViewC with code:

```
[[self navigationItem] setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

I have pushed tab bar controller (tabbarC) after ViewC . In the view controller associated with the first tab in tabbarC I have tried hiding the back button  with the code:

```
 [[[self tabBarController] navigationItem] setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

But the back button is still visible When i click it; it disappears... can any one help me hiding the back button for all the views in the tabbarC.

Comment: in which method u placed that code.... is it viewDidLoad?

Comment: use [[navC navigationItem] setHidesBackButton:YES];

Comment: @Spynet i tried in both viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear with no result

Comment: did you add your tabbar view controller programmatically?

Comment: @Neo yes i have added it programmatically

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your first view that will appear when you push to your tabbarviewcontroller set this

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
      [super viewWillAppear:animated];
      self.tabBarController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
}
```

Comment: In iOS 6.2 after this code (using a programmatic segue - i.e. `performSegueWithIdentifier`) I see the back button is inactive but still visible. Indeed, this thing can have very much to do with your navigation stack and programmatic segues, so pay a little attention in such situations. 
My suggestion is that if segues are used, put `- setHidesBackButton` selector call in your source view controller's `- prepareForSegue` selector.

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad of ViewC do this:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Also tab selected view controller's viewWillAppear method

```
[self.navigationController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view just write this line..it will hide back button .. **tested**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
}
```